# On the way of finding the domain of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-1|-\left[x\right]}}$,$\left[x\right]$
denotes the greatest integer function on $x$, then the domain of $f(x)$ is

(a) $(-1,1)$

(b) $(-\infty,1)$

(c) $(-\infty,-1)$

(d) None of these.

**MY Approach** $\Longrightarrow$

|x-1| - $\left[x\right]$ >0$\Longrightarrow$|x-1| >$\left[x\right]$

This implies two results

(1) $x-1>\left[x\right]$ $\Longrightarrow x < x-1\Longrightarrow0
< -1$ { A Contradiction}

(2) $x-1 < -\left[x\right]$ $\Longrightarrow$ $x < 1-x \Longrightarrow x<
\frac{1}{2}$

**My Result** $x \in (-\infty, \frac{1}{2})$.
But this is not in the options and book says (a) is correct!

Comment: why peoples are finding my question unuseful . Please tell me first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case $(2)$ 
\begin{align*}
x-1 &< -[x]
\implies x+[x] < 1.
\end{align*}
Now $x+[x] \geqslant x+x-1$.
Therefore $2x<2$ $\implies$ $x < 1$. I think option (b) is right. We can also verify this by putting $x=-2$.

Comment: Did i made any calculation error ? that led me to a wrong answer

Comment: Yes. I think you did a mistake when you wrote $x < 1-x$.

Comment: please provide   steps between x+[x]<1.and  x+[x]⩾x+x−1

Comment: We got upto $x+[x] <1$. Now we use the fact that $[x] \geqslant x-1$, which gives 
$x+[x] \geqslant x+x-1$  (by adding $x$ on both sides). Combining we get
\begin{align*}
x+x-1 \leqslant x+[x] <1.
\end{align*}
Hope all clear now.